# Inserting values into hashMap from file in java

Tags: java

I want to insert entries into a `HashMap` that I am obtaining by parsing them from a file using a `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
String line = currentLine(filepath, pos1);
String endLine = currentLine(filepath, pos2);
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != endLine;){
    if (line.contains("START")){                    
        // [... parsing line ...]
        dataStore.put(startId, dateTime);
    } else {
        // [... parsing line ...]
        dataStore.remove(endId);                                
    }
}
```

But when I check `dataStore` (a `HashMap`) it is empty.

Comment: That seems like a ridiculous way to iterate over lines.

Comment: Having a variable and function both named `currentLine` doesn't help either.

Comment: I can"t insert items into HashMap by this way?

Comment: else() with brackets?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. I would expect that the hashmap IS empty because the only time you put() is when a line starts with "START" and we have no idea what your input is.

Comment: Unless you can prove you have `startId`s without matching `endId`s, I'd say your code is working the way you intended.

Comment: Try to learn to use a debugger, and check if it actually run the line of `dataStore.put(....)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a cleaner way to read lines from a text file.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
String line = null;
int lineNo = 0;     

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    lineNo++; 

    if (lineNo < starLine) continue;
    if (lineNo > endLine) break;

    if (line.contains("START")){                    
        // [... parsing line ...]
        dataStore.put(startId, dateTime);
    } else {
        // [... parsing line ...]
        dataStore.remove(endId);
    }
}
```

This should work perfectly find at lease with an existing text file with the data you are expecting in it (We don't know where `startId`, `endId` and `dateTime` came from).

Comment: I know that it would work, bur I need only the lines in interval (startLine, endLine)

Comment: @user2842269 post and example of a file

Comment: If `startLine > 1` then `lineNo` will always remain 1 and all the file would be traversed without doing anything, `lineNo++` shall be before if conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new version of your program that will likely accomplish what you are attempting to do. This version uses regular expressions to match entries of the desired format, without needing to restrict the lines viewed to avoid errors.

If it is necessary to parse only a subset of the file's valid entries, then they should be filtered based on the actual field values, not based on line numbers. (The usual type of filtering needed in this type of application is based on date.)

Also, I have used a number of language features only available in Java 7. If you absolutely must use Java 6, it should be relatively easy to change the try-with-resources to something that works in Java 6.

The regular expression and parsing directives I used may not be exactly what you need for this application; if so please change them. They are based on the assumption that your entries are formatted something like `START 848297 "2013 January 9 12:46:04 AM"` or `END 848297`; if the date is instead given as a Unix timestamp, you should instead use something like `new Date(Integer.parseInt(match.group(3)))` to construct the date object; other formats may call for using specialized `DateFormat` instances to parse them

```
File inputFile = new File("fooFile.txt");
HashMap<Integer, Date> dataStore = new HashMap<>();
//Date begin = new Date(), end = new Date(); //for date filtering, if needed

Pattern entry = Pattern.compile("(START)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*"(.*)"|(END)\\s*(\\d+)");

try(Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile))){
//for buffering, use `new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)))`

    while(in.hasNext(entry)){
        MatchResult match = in.match();

        switch(match.group(1)){
        case "START":
            int startID = Integer.parseInt(match.group(2));
            Date dateTime = DateFormat.parseDate(match.group(3));

            //if you need to filter by date, uncomment the if blocks
            //if(dateTime.before(begin)) break; //don't process dates before begin
            //if(dateTime.before(end)) break; //don't process dates after end

            dataStore.put(startID, dateTime);
            break;
        case "END":
            int endID = Integer.parseInt(match.group(2));
            dataStore.remove(endID);
            break;
        default:
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
    }
} catch (InputMismatchException | IOException ex){
    throw ex; //please change if other behaviors are desired
}
```